# Paste transparency from Photoshop into Flash

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-flash, transparency

I am working with a PSD that has layers. Each layer has a transparent background as well as the base layer. I was curious if it is possible to copy a layer and paste into Flash preserving the transparency?

Basically I want each layer to "fly" in to form the logo. I have accomplished the animation part, but since the transparent background is converted to white, it looks pretty ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the only way I found was to copy the layer paste into a new image in photoshop (which preserved the transparency) and save as a png. Then `import to stage` in Flash.

Answer (score 1):

You can import PSD directly into to Flash.